# SSL error in Standalone Unity3d build: couldn't create a context: error:140A90F1:lib(20):func(169):reason(241)

Tags: c#, ssl, unity-game-engine, https

I'm using standard `WWW` class.

Android/iOS builds work fine, but when trying to use https in Standalone build, got error:

> SL: couldn't create a context:
>   error:140A90F1:lib(20):func(169):reason(241)

How can I solve this?

Comment: Judging by [this bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=768997) and [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282939/openssl-ssl-ctx-newsslv3-method-returns-null), the problem sounds like a bug. Are you loading any plugins or libraries that might be clobbering the SSL lib? If you can duplicate this with an empty project, it may be a bug in Unity.

Comment: @rutter will try with empty project

Comment: @rutter I've tested it. No such error in empty project =/

Comment: That may imply that something in your project is causing (or just encountering) the problem. You could contact official Unity support to see if they know anything, or you could try re-adding components from your project until you get it to happen again.

Comment: @rutter I've tried to copy all used plugins to my empty project, but still works on new project. Will ask Unity support.